# Does PHP support template classes?

Tags: php

I have a class that returns stdClass.

Every time I extend it, I supply the constructor with some kind of type (as a string), and all of the methods returns stdClass of that type.

I would like to do - just like in C++/Java/Typescript:

`new B<User>` so the code knows to expect a user being returned.

Over more, I would like to do:

`class A extends B<User> {`

I can't find any trace of mentioning it in the php.net website, or anywhere else. So is there support for it or not? (I realise probably not, but wanna be sure)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class template in PHP like in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605535/class-template-in-php-like-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, php doesn't not support template classes.

But [HACK](http://hacklang.org/) does.